# Things to do with expired tablets and ointments

Tags: home

In my house, I have lots of tablets and ointments and I am planning to throw them into the dustbin. Instead, I want to do something innovative with them and not  throwing them out. Cool ideas welcome...

Comment: Expired tablets and ointments can be hazardous. Many of them, on contact, will result in unwanted physical conditions. That is why they have an expiry. I understand your idea, but it is inadvisable. Do not retain any medication beyond its expiry. make sure you dispose them in a safe manner.

Comment: In the UK, and probably other jurisdictions, putting expired medication in domestic waste or drainage is illegal.  They must be returned to a pharmacy for treatment as medical waste.

Comment: It's not a good idea to try to recycle tablets, ointments or their containers, these are chemicals past their life cycle. The best and only option should be to dispose of them properly.

Comment: @Chenmunka - pretty sure it's not illegal in the UK. They ask you dispose of sharps in a sensible manner however my diabetic sister was told she can dispose of used insulin needles once decapped(with the little clippy tool that takes the point off) in a empty bleach bottle and put this in normal household waste.

Answer (score 1):

If you have capsules like the one given in the image below, you could carefully empty the medicine enclosed within the capsule and use the jacket as **beads** and use them for **decorations**. However, these jackets are water soluble. So keep that in mind. [image: Capsules]

Answer (score 0):

Remove the tablets from its cover and you can use this cover strip as key chain.You can also use this tablet [cover](https://www.google.co.in/search?q=tablet+strip&client=ubuntu&channel=fs&biw=1535&bih=805&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiDx8qp7MvJAhVEC44KHRnvBl0Q_AUIBigB#imgrc=zMdYXyjSpVQYHM%3A) for sprouting seeds for your vegetable farm cultivation.You can sprinkle each dips with a little amount of soil,water and seed required.There after the tablets can be given to drug collectors. The ointment covers can be used as drip tips of drip irrigation which is a new type of [irrigation](http://driptips.toro.com/drip-irrigation-definitions/) for your farm.